# In Nuxt 3, Props shoes correctly inside Template but show wrong data in code inside Setup Script

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

in Nuxt 3, I'm stack in props passed to component!

```
 <FileItem 
    
    v-for="file in main.workflowsFiles " :key="file.id" :myFileItem="file"  >
 </FileItem>
```

and this my props in child component:

```
const props=defineProps({

myFileItem: Object})
```

it's work fine when I display it in HTML:

```
{{ myFileItem }}
```

but when I want to log it or use inside my code it's gave show the only first data props data

```
  const approve= ()=> {
    console.log(props.myFileItem);
  
}
```

log result:

```
 {
    "id": 88,
    "folderId": 71,
    "fileName": "client-4.png",
    "name": "client-4.png",
    "userId": "38c62309-5d93-49e6-f74b-08db95b3572f",
    "size": 9
    
}
```

even when I try to show the second item props data

Comment: I think we need more info. With what we got, the issue would be with `main.workflowsFiles`

Comment: main.workflowsFiles came from Pinia store file. I will use a const array of object to see if it's matter

Comment: No effect, log show first element only even when I click the second one or third one

Comment: You'll need to show enough code that can reproduce the problem.  Say we put all your current code in a [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-95yp75?file=app.vue,FileItem.vue) in an attempt to reproduce with minimal changes to make the code run.  Currently, the problem is not reproducible.  Please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit the question with enough information that others can then reproduce and fully understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all, The problem was in a modal component that use tailwind-elements, I created a normal modal without additional library in its work